# Sort list of dicts by multiple values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

**I have the following dict**

```
tempdata = {'logs': [
    {'starttime':'901',
     'time':'5'
     },
    {'starttime':'902',
     'time':'3'
     },
    {'starttime':'900',
     'time':'2'
     },    
    {'starttime':'901',
     'time':'2'
     },
    {'starttime':'905',
     'time':'1'
     },
    {'starttime':'904',
     'time':'1'
     }
]
}
```

I want to primarily sort by `starttime`. Which I do perfectly with:

```
 tempdata['logs'] = sorted(tempdata['logs'],key=lambda k: k['starttime'])
```

But now, I want to sort them by time as well.

**Expected output:**

```
tempdata = {'logs': [
    {'starttime':'900',
    'time':'2'
    },
    {'starttime':'901',
     'time':'2'
     },
    {'starttime':'901',
     'time':'5'
     },
    {'starttime':'902',
     'time':'3'
     },
    {'starttime':'904',
     'time':'1'
     },
    {'starttime':'905',
     'time':'1'
     }
]
}
```

How can I accomplish this task? I've looked up the sorted(), and can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Mephy I couldn't find that one, that's perfect! I'll leave this question here, as my one does reference to dicts/lists, and the other is referring to lists/tuples.

Comment: Why are these questions always f'ing easy INTs!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sort them using a tuple as a key like this:

```
tempdata['logs'] = sorted(tempdata['logs'],
                          key=lambda k: (k['starttime'], k['time']))
```

Tuples are compared by each element in order.

And as a side note, this way the values are compared as strings, not as numbers. Don't know if that's relevant for you.